# Different Classes separated with comma in SCSS using @for

Tags: css, sass

I want to render this css below using SCSS:

```
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--1>.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--1,
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--default--1>.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--1,
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--2>.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--2,
...
..
. {
    margin-left: $pc-100;
}
```

Using this @for below:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .aem-Grid.aem-Grid--#{$i}>.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--#{$i} {
        margin-left: $pc-100;
    }
}
```

But this code renders all separated:

```
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--1 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--1 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--2 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--2 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
...
..
.
```

I've tried to use "&, &aem-Grid..." but render the same css. Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Did you intend a "scss" tag instead of "sass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at `@extend`. Documentation https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

**Input**

```
$pc: 1000;

%margin-styles {
     margin-left: $pc - 100;
}

@for $i from 1 through 12 {
     .aem-Grid.aem-Grid--#{$i}>.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--#{$i} {
         @extend %margin-styles; 
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--12 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--12, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--11 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--11, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--10 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--10, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--9 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--9, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--8 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--8, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--7 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--7, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--6 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--6, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--5 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--5, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--4 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--4, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--3 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--3, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--2 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--2, 
.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--1 > .aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--offset--default--1 {
    margin-left: 900;
}
```

Comment: @GuillermoMila Glad i was able to help. Appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted as it will help other SO users who are looking for similar solutions